# Meteor: Can't update fields with $set

Tags: meteor

I'm learning Meteor. So far, I've been able to initialize properties on User.profile with the following:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$set:cardObject});
```

I'd like to update those properties but when I use the same technique I get this:

```
errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Access denied", details: undefined, message: "Access denied [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
```

It will let me $unset the properties though:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$unset: cardObject});
```

This is strange to me. I can delete properties but not modify them.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please indicate if you have any allow/deny rules for users, and what a sample `cardObject` looks like.

Comment: @DavidWeldon This problem was due to simple typo on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the full codebase, so I'm guessing, but based on your code snippet, it might be because `cardObject` doesn't complete the `$set` commmand properly.  a typical `$set` command looks like this:

```
 ...{"$set" : {"key": "value"}}...
```

so, it may depend on what is in your `cardObject`.

Whereas your `$unset` will work just fine because you only need the key to perform an unset.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That was one of my initial thoughts, but I've checked the schema several times, and I'm almost positive they're identical. I've been working for a long time so its possible I'm missing something simple. Perhaps a set of rested eyes will be the difference.

Comment: So, what does a typical `cardObject` look like (in JSON)?

Comment: I stand corrected...The card object was being passed a rogue '.'. Fresh eyes win again. Thanks for your help.